# XMPP Multi-User Chat Room Disconnecting Error

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I was able to create a MUC chat room using javascript, XMPP, Strophe, and openFire. The room was created and different user can join. Below is the code used to create the room:

```
function onConnected(status)
{
    if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) 
    {
        con.addHandler(on_presence, null, "presence");
        con.addHandler(on_public_message, null, "message", "groupchat");
        con.addHandler(on_private_message, null, "message", "chat");

        con.muc.init(con);
        var d = $pres({"from":"louis@louis-tosh","to":"myroom@conference.louis-tosh/Louis"})
        .c("x",{"xmlns":"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"});

        con.send(d.tree());
        con.muc.createInstantRoom("myroom@conference.louis-tosh");
    }
}
```

The "myroom" is now created and automatically "louis@louis-tosh" joined the room.
Waiting a few second, louis@louis-tosh user is suddenly disconnected (left the room). As this user disconnect, an on presence stanza is alerted. The on presence code is below:

```
function on_presence (presence)
{
    var from = $(presence).attr('from');
    var room = Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(from);
    var nick = Strophe.getResourceFromJid(from);

    var show = $(presence).find("show").text();
    if (show === "" || show === "chat") 
    {
        alert('Presence From: ' + from + "(Online)");
    } 
    else if(show === "dnd")
    {
        alert('Presence From: ' + from + "(Busy)");
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Presence From: ' + from + "(Away)");
    }

    return true;
}
```

I need to know why this disconnecting issue is occurring and if their is any suggestions on the above code. Any help or suggestion is really useful.

Comment: What's the stanza that was received from the jabber server?